# Group by Activity Date in Search Kit (rather than date and time)

Tags: activities, searchkit

Is there a way in Search Kit to group activity results by Activity Date rather than date and time?

I am looking to build a report that will allow someone to compare daily totals (and other details) of activities. Because the Activity Date field is a date and a time, activities from different times throughout the day are not grouped together.

I used Field Transformations to have it display in the results as "(Date Only) Activity Date", but that did not seem to effect Group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the same thing as https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2485, which I also ran into. Short answer is not yet.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be relatively inexpensive if someone wanted to sponsor this addition to SearchKit. Please contact me about this at https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/messages/@coleman

Answer (score 0):

This is now available thanks to https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23434

[image]